# UITableViewCell delete button not appearing

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableview that I am putting inside a JASidePanel controller (https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) I have set the delegate and datasource in my init method and I have implemented the canEditRowAtIndexPath methods and they are are being called when I swipe on a tableview cell but nothing happens visually. I have looked through other questions and have implemented all of the suggestions but can't get the delete button to display. Does anyone know what would cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must implement the `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method and the `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` data source method. Without these, the delete won't appear for a cell.

I assume you are returning `YES` from your `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` data source method (at least for the appropriate rows).

Comment: I eventually figured this out. I chose this answer because all you need to do is implement those two methods and it works. I had implemented these two methods but the delete button was hidden underneath the center panel controller of the JASidePanel... I just had to shrink the width of the tableview and it appeared..

Comment: @AFraser - actually, your comment helped me answer my own question as my problem was very similar (right hand side of master view (in custom split view controller) was obscured by the detail view).  I'd certainly suggest putting it as an answer as your question does mention the JASidePanel controller.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this class' own method for deleting cell.?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
      int k = [[tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue];

      //Remove object from index 'k'.
   }
}
```

It may be help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To perform the delete action for UITableView on swiping the TableViewCell. We have to implement the three methods which are as follows:-

This method will display the delete button on swipe the TableViewCell.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
       editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
  NSUInteger count = [posts count];

  if (row < count) {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
  } else {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
  }
}
```

This method is called when user delete a row on swipe of TableViewCell and the swiped row will be deleted on tapping delete button.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
        forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
  NSUInteger count = [posts count];

  if (row < count) {
    [posts removeObjectAtIndex:row];
  }
}
```

Finally this method is called to update the table view after deleting the row.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                   didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  [self updateViewTitle];
  [tableView reloadData];
}
```